# GGplot | Barchart for counting characters as fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

Need some help getting this bar chart to form. I get errors about not being able to count characters.
Trying to get it to look like this:

[image]

```
ggplot(Interview_State_Data,aes(x = Interview_Stage, 
                          y = as.factor(Level_Simplified), 
                          fill = Level_Simplified)) +
  

  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")


structure(list(Interview_Stage = c("Third Onsite", "Recruiter Phone Screen", 
"Second Onsite", "Third Onsite", "Recruiter Phone Screen", "Second Onsite"
), Level_Simplified = c("MR", "IC", "MR", "MR", "MR", "MR")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: If you need counts, have you tried with `stat="count"` ?

Comment: I didn't even realize I had that. Yup that solved it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(Interview_Stage_Data,aes(x = Interview_Stage, 
                      #   y = Level_Simplified, #
                          fill = Level_Simplified)) +
  

  geom_bar(stat="count", position="dodge")
```

Changed `geom_bar(stat="identity"`  to `geom_bar(stat="count"` and removed  `y = Level_Simplified` from the code and it ran perfect.

Thanks to @markus